# Coq tactic that adds the value of an inductive term to the context

Tags: coq

Just to give a simple example of this issue I keep running into, suppose I wish to prove `forall f : nat -> bool, exists i j, i<>j /\ f i = f j.`  The obvious thing to do is check the values of `f 0, f 1, f 2,` and proceed accordingly.  However, if I simply say `destruct (f 0)`, Coq doesn't modify the goal, since `f 0` doesn't occur as a subterm.  Therefore, I don't have the information I want about what value `f 0` is currently taking.  Ideally, I would like for Coq to add a witness `H : f 0 = false` to the context so I can keep track of it.

What I've been doing to get around these issues is to prove an auxiliary lemma `bool_destruct : forall b : bool, b = false \/ b = true`.  Now, if I say `destruct (bool_destruct (f 0))` Coq will add the desired `H` to the context.  Naturally, this is tedious when you have to prove this sort of lemma for each inductive type.  Thus, I'm wondering if there is a nice tactic that handles these sorts of situations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The destruct tactic already supports what you want:

```
destruct (f 0) eqn:f_is0.
```

Your idea of using `bool_destruct` is not as bad as you make it to be, for instance, a similar idea plus a pattern generalization feature of the `case` tactic is used in math-comp to provide custom destruct views.